# CASE statement in SQL query in WHERE

Tags: sql

```
  SELECT      "OrdDet"."DetID",                     
              "OrdDet"."ServQty",            
              "OItem"."PlanID",              
  CASE        "OrdDet"."resourceID"          
  WHEN        100522 THEN 1024               
  WHEN        100488 THEN 50                 
  END         "ResourceAmount"               
  FROM        "OrdDet"                       
  JOIN        "Subscription" USING ("subscrip
  JOIN        "PlanRate" USING ("PlanID")                                         
  AND         "Subscription"."PlanID" = "Plan
  WHERE       "OrdDet"."resourceID" IN (10048
  AND         "Subscription"."PlanID" <= 265 
  AND         "Subscription"."PlanID" >= 260 
  AND         "PlanRate"."resourceID" = 10001
  AND         "OItem"."Status" = 40          
  AND         "OIType" IN (60, 80)           
  AND         "SubscrParam"."IncludedValue" != "PlanRate"."includedValue" 
  + ("OrdDet"."ServQty" * "OrdDet"."resourceID")         
  ORDER BY    "OrdDet"."subscriptionID"
```

""")

I need to be able to have "OrdDet"."resourceID" as 1024 or 50 when doing my calculation on this line of the code

```
AND  "SubscrParam"."IncludedValue" != "PlanRate"."includedValue" 
+ ("OrdDet"."ServQty" * "OrdDet"."resourceID")
```

At the moment it is just using the 100522 or 100488.  Also, when i use "ResourceAmount" instead of "OrdDet"."resourceID" it doesn't recognize "ResourceAmount"  Is there anyway I can include the changed values of 1024 or 50 from the case in my calculation in the where?

Comment: what kind of dbms is this? The use of `"` seems awkward

Comment: It's a Relational database, the quotes are just needed.

Comment: OK, but from which vendor and version? :) And please fix your code, it has several uncomplete lines...

Comment: There must be more to this.  Your case syntax appears correct and would return 1024, 50 or null depending on the data in Microsoft SQL Server.  Please provide more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I understand now after rereading the question a few times

Change

```
AND         "SubscrParam"."IncludedValue" != "PlanRate"."includedValue" 
+ ("OrdDet"."ServQty" * "OrdDet"."resourceID")
```

to

```
AND         "SubscrParam"."IncludedValue" != "PlanRate"."includedValue" 
+ ("OrdDet"."ServQty" *  CASE "OrdDet"."resourceID"          
WHEN        100522 THEN 1024               
WHEN        100488 THEN 50                 
END)
```

Comment: Yes that's exactly what was needed, works perfect now, Thanks very much John.